# Cassandra compaction fails: IOError IOException Map failed

Tags: cassandra

We have been running Cassandra 1.0.2 in production for many months, with minimal trouble. Lately, we have started to see consistent failures in all nodes, with this error:

```
ERROR [CompactionExecutor:199] 2013-03-02 00:21:26,179 AbstractCassandraDaemon.java (line 133) Fatal exception in thread Thread[CompactionExecutor:199,1,RMI Runtime]
java.io.IOError: java.io.IOException: Map failed
        at org.apache.cassandra.io.util.MmappedSegmentedFile$Builder.createSegments(MmappedSegmentedFile.java:225)
        at org.apache.cassandra.io.util.MmappedSegmentedFile$Builder.complete(MmappedSegmentedFile.java:202)
        at org.apache.cassandra.io.sstable.SSTableWriter.closeAndOpenReader(SSTableWriter.java:308)
        at org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.CompactionTask.execute(CompactionTask.java:174)
        at org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.CompactionManager$4.call(CompactionManager.java:275)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Map failed
        at sun.nio.ch.FileChannelImpl.map(FileChannelImpl.java:758)
        at org.apache.cassandra.io.util.MmappedSegmentedFile$Builder.createSegments(MmappedSegmentedFile.java:217)
        ... 9 more
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Map failed
        at sun.nio.ch.FileChannelImpl.map0(Native Method)
        at sun.nio.ch.FileChannelImpl.map(FileChannelImpl.java:755)
        ... 10 more
INFO [Thread-2] 2013-03-02 00:21:26,222 MessagingService.java (line 488) Shutting down MessageService...
```

The node dies after this. We remove the oldest data files and start the node again. The node runs for a while, then dies again. This happens for all eight nodes in our ring.
We are using the default compaction strategy (size tiered) and we think it is the best choice for our problem domain.

**Q:** Why is this happening and what should we do to fix it?

Comment: Looks a lot like https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-3201, although that says fixed in 1.0.0.  Someone else is reporting the same problem on 1.0.2: http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/cassandra-user/201202.mbox/%3CCAOZgscd_w08mcq59wgsm=1N06p2WOXQKC6U9uurs3+zoke-NcA@mail.gmail.com%3E. Can you paste the full stack trace?

Comment: I'd also recommend upgrading to 1.0.12 since there have been many bug fixes since your version. Check the CHANGES.txt file for things to check before upgrading.

Comment: CASSANDRA-3201 only confirms that C* will exit when a memory-map operation fails. It does not tell me what I should do to prevent these errors from occurring. Let's say we had a 30% volume increase last week. Is this why the mem-map fails? Full stack trace posted.

Comment: The problem was solved by doing the following: (1) upgrade RH Linux from 4.5 to 6.1. (2) upgrade C* to 1.2.2. (3) update kernel file limits. (4) stop running forced compactions. (5) start running "nodetool cleanup" every night. Of all these changes, we believe that (1) was the most important.